# Tinymce - Bullet Points

Tags: tinymce, ssrs-2012, tinymce-4

Whenever we use Tinymce - Bullet Points or numbering within SSRS (Reporting Servicese) it appears there are extra spacing has been created at the bottom of the actual text. Is there a way around this? Has anyone else being having the same issue?

Within the HTML code it generates it doesn't seems like that there is any line spacing. However, as long as you insert a bullet point within the report it indicates about 1-2 line spaces at the end of the TinyMce article.

For an example if the entered text is as per below, there will be extra line spacing appearing at the end after the paragraph 3. This is only visual within the report writter. On web within the TinyMCE there are no spaces after the paragraph 03.

```
Doc Start

Paragraph 01

Paragraph 02

Bullet Points Start
    -
    -
    -

Paragraph 03

Extra Spacing
Extra Spacing

Doc End
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by "it appears there are extra spacing has been created at the bottom of the actual text"?  TinyMCE will render content based on the CSS that is provided to the editor so if things don't look as you expect you likely need to look at the CSS you are passing to TinyMCE.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Please refer to the updated question above. Hope this will be clearer.